# How to get the "real" colors when exporting a GDI drawing to bmp

Tags: c#, bitmap, gdi, system.drawing, color-mapping

I'm developing a ASP.Net web handler that returns images making a in-memory `System.Windows.Forms.Control` and then exports the rendered control as a bitmap compressed to PNG, using the method `DrawToBitmap()`. The classes are fully working by now, except for a problem with the color assignment. By example, this is a Gauge generated by the web handler.

[image: The gauge]

The colors assigned to the inner parts of the gauge are red (`#FF0000`), yellow (`#FFFF00`) and green (`#00FF00`) but I only get a dully version of each color (`#CB100F` for red, `#CCB70D` for yellow and `#04D50D` for green).

The background is a bmp file containing the color gradient. The color loss happens whether the background is a gradient as the sample, a black canvas, a white canvas, a transparent canvas, even when there is not a background set.

- With black background

[image: With black background]

- With transparent background

[image: With a transparent background]

- With a white background

[image: With a white background]

- Without a background set

[image: Without a background set]

- With pixel format in Format32bppArgb

[image: With pixelformat Format32bppArgb]

I've tried multiple bitmap color deeps, output formats, compression level, etc. but none of them seems to work. Any ideas?

This is a excerpt of the source code:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(w, h, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);
Image bgimage = (Image) HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("GraphicResources", "GaugeBackgroundImage");
Canvas control_canvas = new Canvas(); //inherits from Control
....
//the routine that makes the gauge
....
control_canvas.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, w, h));
```

Comment: You *really* want that color badly... ;-)  Or did you mean "How to get..."?

Comment: I'm only want to set a color and actually get that color. These are only a example, of course I don't want a Christmas tree in my application ;)

Comment: Holy crap, I just realized the typo!

Comment: What happens when you change the Pixel Format to Format32bppArgb?

Comment: It is already in that format. However, changing the value to Format24bppRgb, Format32bppRgb, Format16bppRgb555, even 48 and 64 bits don't affect the result. The resulting image always loses the color information provided.

Comment: What happens if you take the Bitmap (bmp) and saved that to file directly?

Comment: @Rodrigo: It's not technically in that format... It's in Format32bppPArgb so the individual color components are premultiplied.

Comment: @Jacob G, just added the format at the bottom of the image list. The same result

Comment: You're not showing us enough code.

Comment: @Mark, the class is 1K lines long. What particular piece of code you need? I will provide it asap, this issue is driving me nuts with the design department.

Comment: Perhaps we would also need the input background images. Have you tried to change those to different output formats? Are you drawing directly to the bg image?

Comment: (I've done my share of GDI+ with System.Drawing.Graphics class and I've never seen that Canvas class.) I second Nate; save the Bitmap directly and see if it looks right. Does the bitmap have correct colors anywhere in the process? If not then why would it be correct at the end? If it IS correct anywhere along the process, then clearly the later (last?) steps are messing things up. I don't trust that DrawToBitmap part.

Comment: Rodrigo, you can learn a lot by cutting the function down to the bare minimum that shows the problem. You can replace it from scratch, perhaps starting by drawing a single rectangle. Or you can just clip out large pieces as long as the problem remains. If you figure out what the problem was by this process come back and tell us, otherwise post whatever you have left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Canvas was a class provided by a third party. We found a bug in their package, they released a new version, and the problem was finally solved. Thanks anyway for your time!

Answer (score 1):

When you paint the colors, check to make sure the alpha channel is set correctly as well.  If you have some alpha it will blend with that dark background and give you a darker color.

Comment: the result is the same whether a background is present or not

Comment: I've been trying to come up with a better answer.  Maybe if you posted your code or sent it to me to "tinker" with?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this with only PNGs? I hit this problem with PNGs (or JPEGS?) in a browser long ago, but IIRC GIFs eliminated the problem:

- [The Sad Story of PNG Gamma “Correction](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/png-gamma/)

NOTE that I'm not saying GIFs will solve your problem in the long wrong but it may tell you if the PNG write/read is the problem. Try it, try BMP, try something. Don't believe the PNG. You could try dumping the r g b values to a log file (or to disk as raw and importing into Photoshop and) see what the numbers are before writing out the bitmap. (Use [LockBits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.lockbits.aspx); there are tutorials for code on getting bytes in and out of Bitmaps).

Comment: @Mark: Good point. Really these images look like someone loaded them in Photoshop and hit Ctrl+Y (CMYK mode) which makes things look like they came out of a printer, eliminating bright colors.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that you have really bright yellow parts on that triangle pointer, so the problem is likely with the background image. Are you drawing those arcs with primitives or loading a bitmap? You could be having gamma problems, color space problems, etc. depending on the input format, assuming you are using an image for the red/yellow/green meter part. Try drawing those shapes in code if you are using an image. Whatever code makes the yellow triangle is getting the bright colors, so use the same image format or Brush or whatever makes the yellow triangle work.

Comment: The triangle is filled with Color.Gold, but neither met the specified.